# Magento 2.2.4. How to place authorize.net seal in middle blocks of pages?

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

We have been trying to place the authorize.net seal in particular section of page. But after adding the script generated from authorize.net , by default seal logo goes to the bottom of the page. Any thoughts how to fix the issue?

code we have added on site:

```
<div class="AuthorizeNetSeal"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var ANS_customer_id="3b297692-6f60-4c80-b5ba-2baa27845f29";
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net:443/anetseal/seal.js" ></script>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Please share your code or check for any inline css

Comment: i have updated the question with code. Hope that helps

Comment: unfortunately seal is not showing for me due to missing Id! just check css for  class `AuthorizeNetSeal` it should have some css which is forcing element to render at specific position

Comment: ok i have added the valid id now. I actually removed the class and tried still no luck. Basically 2 script tags are trimmed from div and gets populated at the bottom of page